# AuthenticatonError when making requests to Microsoft's Graph API

Tags: office365, office365-apps

I am trying to query the Graph API for information on user's calendars. I'm currently able to query /me with no issue:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "id": "---",
    "businessPhones": [
        "123456789"
    ],
    "displayName": "john smith",
    "givenName": "john",
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": null,
    "mobilePhone": "+123456789",
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
    "surname": "",
    "userPrincipalName": "person@org.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

However, querying for any resource (ie: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars`) gives the error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticatonError",
        "message": "Error authenticating with resource",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "de91f00f-fd39-44cc-8856-757dc4a5ee24",
            "date": "2016-07-22T14:11:04"
        }
    }
}
```

I've been googling any nobody else seems to have this issue. My app is properly registered and has every permission enabled. I am calling the API via Angular with ADAL. The app gets the token and authenticates with no issue (`isAuthenticated: true` in the userInfo) Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: Is it possible that you first set up the app with just sign in permissions, tested it (consented) with just /me and then added the remaining permissions? If so, your consent was recorded only with the original permissions and because you already consented, aren't being prompted again even though the permissions changed.

One thing to try is, while signing in (in the https://login.microsoftonline.com...) add &prompt=consent to force consent again and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe that's the issue in this case. The app had properly configured permissions from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving this issue by ditching the graph api and querying https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/calendars. The docs at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#GetCalendarView appear to have the incorrect api endpoints.

Our app's version of Angular is 1.2 and the version of adal.js is 1.0.7. 
Instead of using Azure AD, I used the registration @ dev.outlook.